# Cannot find the shared library (java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError)

Tags: java, eclipse

I need to run my Eclipse project on a different laptop. The following error occurs when running the code:

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: The shared library C:\Archivos de programa\ECLiPSe 6.0\lib\i386_nt\ec_java_load.dll could not be found.**

How can I configure the correct path to "ec_java_load.dll"? It should be "C:\Program Files..." instead on the current one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see this a lot when moving eclipse projects around. I also see eclipse mentioned in your error string, so I think I'm on the right track.

To fix this, you have to go into the project settings - build path, remove the old non-working lib and add the right one for the environment you are in